# How do I pass the logged in windows user to an aspx web application

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, active-directory

I have written a simple .aspx web application using C# in Visual Studio 2012. I would like to have a 2 level functionality based on whether the person's employeeID accessing the application is in a specific Active Directory group.

I call the following function passing it a group name

```
private static bool checkGroup( string group ) 
{
        WindowsIdentity id = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent ( );
        //System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal wp 
        //   = (WindowsPrincipal)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal;

        WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal ( id );

        if ( principal.IsInRole ( group ) ) {
            return true;
        } else { return false; }

}
```

Based on the returned value I set the visibility of the various controls. Nothing I have tried so far seems to work.

The web server is running IIS7 on Windows Server 2008 R2 and the app is set to run on Framework 4.0 Classic set to Network. Authentication is set to windows authentication.

The application itself works perfectly from the web server except for this security feature and this function works perfectly from Visual Studio but when I put it on the web server it doesn't seem to be able to pick up the logged in user. I need to be able to get the log in id of the Windows User accessing the web page.

Comment: Sorry - should have mentioned Employee ID = Windows Login ID

Comment: Have you got `<identity impersonate="true" />` in your web.config?

Comment: Does the web.config authentication parameter match what is on the server?

Comment: Yes ... sorry ... the web.config to matches authentication parameters should have mentioned that as well